# how do i use wkhtmltopdf (the dll version) asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, dll, wkhtmltopdf

I've downloded the wkhtmltox0.dll from here http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list . I am working in asp.net  and  i can't find any example of how to
 use it!
All i found were examples of how to use the .exe version and it works just fine.

Does anybody can provide me an example?

Answer (score 3):

There is a github project (and nuget package) that does it all.

https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Pechkin/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pechkin.Synchronized/

Answer (score 1):

For the [various](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin#q-why-my-web-app-hangscrashes-even-after-ive-started-using-synchronizedpechkin) [pitfalls](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin/pull/42) of using the [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin) wrapper, it might be safer to just call the command line with wkhtmltopdf.exe directly.

There's already a ready wrapper here: [Codaxy wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/codaxy/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/NuGet/Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf/content/PdfConvert.cs).

Comment: I agree, even I had tried using DLL in various ways but it does not  work smoothly. EXE with wrapper is the best